# why substring() wont give error, but charAt() gives error

Tags: substring

```
String str = "Nobody ever went broke by buying IBM";

System.out.println("Length of this string: "+ str.length());
System.out.println("The character at position 36: "+ str.charAt(36)); // i get error here
System.out.println("The substring from 36: "+ str.substring(36));// why no error here
```

I get output as follows :

```
Length of this string: 36
The character at position 36: error
The substring from 36:
```

My question is why it is not showing error when when substring(36) is called, instead i am getting answer as empty space. Logically there is no char at index 36?? But i get error when i call charAt(36) because there is no 36 index ??

Comment: If this is Java, then indexes start at zero.

Comment: Adding a language tag would be a good start (although I agree with larsmans that it *looks* like java)

Answer (score 2):

This is how these functions are supposed to work. (Assuming java) .

From the oracle [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int%29):

`substring` methods throws an  `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if beginIndex is negative or larger than the length of this String object.

36 is the length of your string which is not larger than the length of your string therefore call to `substring` succeeds.

`charAt` fails because the 36 characters are located from index 0 to 35. Have a look at the documentation for charAt